# Converting DRY enlarge ibox-content function into dynamic one

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, button

Ive created a bunch of DRY functions that will increase a bootstraps ibox-content from whatever column size it was originally to the maximum column size(12). So i need help to create a dynamic function that would work for all buttons that have the enlarge function by increasing the ibox-content to the maximum column size when clicked and then revert back to its original column size when its clicked again.

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/22538/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6" id="elements">
        <div class="ibox float-e-margins" id="elementBox">           
            <div class="ibox-title" tabindex="0">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-go-1">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-fullscreen"></i>
                </button> 
            </div>
            <div class="ibox-content short-box" id="ibox-1">
                content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 $(".btn-go-1").click(function () {
     $("#elements").toggleClass("col-lg-6 col-lg-12", 1000, "linear");
     $("#ibox-1").toggleClass("short-box large-box", 1000, "linear");
 });
```

Comment: What is your question/desired output?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki   I remade the description

Comment: Your code work fine, tested with `col-xs`.... https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/22537/

Comment: I know it works fine but if i want to use it on multiple ibox-contents i have to create the exact same function multiple times instead of using just one for all off them.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki i also added a jsfiddle to maybe help explain it better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Give your containers same class, e.g `container`.
2. Give your buttons same  class, e.g `btn-go`.
3. Add **[`data-*`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** attribute to save the default size of every container, e.g :

   ```
   <div data-default='col-xs-6' class="container col-xs-6" id="strageties">
   ```
4. Create one click event for `btn-go` :

   ```
   $(".btn-go").click(function () {
       var container = $(this).parents('.container');
       var default_size = container.data('default');

       //Toggle between default size and max size
       container.toggleClass(default_size+" col-xs-12",1000,"linear");
       container.find(".ibox-content").toggleClass("short-box large-box", 1000, "linear");
   });
   ```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(".btn-go").click(function () {
  var container = $(this).parents('.container');
  var default_size = container.data('default');
  
  container.toggleClass(default_size+" col-xs-12", 1000, "linear");
  container.find(".ibox-content").toggleClass("short-box large-box", 1000, "linear");
});
```

```css
.container{
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div data-default='col-xs-6' class="container col-xs-6" id="elements">
    <div class="ibox float-e-margins">           
      <div class="ibox-title" tabindex="0">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-go">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-fullscreen"></i>
        </button> 
      </div>
      <div class="ibox-content short-box" id="ibox-1">
        content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div data-default='col-xs-6' class="container col-xs-6" id="strageties">
    <div class="ibox float-e-margins">           
      <div class="ibox-title" tabindex="0">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-go">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-fullscreen"></i>
        </button> 
      </div>
      <div class="ibox-content short-box" id="ibox-2">
        content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div data-default='col-xs-8' class="container col-xs-8" id="map">
    <div class="ibox float-e-margins">           
      <div class="ibox-title" tabindex="0">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-go">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-fullscreen"></i>
        </button> 
      </div>
      <div class="ibox-content short-box" id="ibox-3">
        content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats awesome, but before i accept you missed the id's (ibox-1, ibox-2, ibox-3) so how can i have that part of the function be dynamic instead of hard coded?

Comment: For some reason it doesnt work when the class is col-lg-6, only when its col-xs-6. Still will accept answer but im not sure if you know why